# javascript, json value counting?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to count value's number.
Here is json.

```
x = {"first" : ["apple", "banana", "car", "day"],
     "second" : ["apple","car"],
     "third" : ["day"],
     "fourth" " [],
     "fifth" : ["apple"]
}
```

And I need these output.

```
object..???['apple']
>>>3
object..???['banana']
>>>1
object..???['car']
>>>2
object..???['day']
>>>2
object..???['elephant']
>>>0
```

What kind of code should I use?

I tried the following but it isn't working:

```
Object.values(x['day']).length;
```

Comment: Check out Array.reduce.

Comment: @rayhatfield not sure how that works with an Object

Comment: `Object.values(x).reduce(...)`

Comment: `Here is json` - no, here is a javascript object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the values in your object and put them into an array using  `Object.values()` and `.flat()`. Then, you can `.filter()` out any items in your values array which are not your desired item. Finally, you can get the `.length` of this array to find how many items matched your search.

See example below:

```js
const x = {
  "first": ["apple", "banana", "car", "day"],
  "second": ["apple", "car"],
  "third": ["day"],
  "fourth": [],
  "fifth": ["apple"]
}

const countItem = (obj, search) =>
  Object.values(obj).flat().filter(item => item === search).length;
  
console.log(countItem(x, "apple")); // 3
console.log(countItem(x, "banana")); // 1
console.log(countItem(x, "car")); // 2
console.log(countItem(x, "day")); // 2
console.log(countItem(x, "elephant")); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten out the object's values and then use a reduce operation to calculate the number of times the key appears in the object:

```js
const x = {
  "first": ["apple", "banana", "car", "day"],
  "second": ["apple", "car"],
  "third": ["day"],
  "fourth": [],
  "fifth": ["apple"]
};

const count = (k) => Object.values(x).flat().reduce((a, v) => a + (k === v ? 1 : 0), 0);

console.log(count('day')); // 2
```